# How do I get data from a dataset to show in a ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, reportviewer, windowsformshost

I have created a ReportViewer within a WindowsFormHost. Here is my XAML code.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdPrintingGrid" Visibility="Visible" Height="440" Margin="105, 0, 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPRTTitle" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18.667" Background="#FFE8F9FF" BorderThickness="0"/>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wfhFormsHost" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="312" Margin="10,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="683">
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="rvWeeklyList" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <Grid x:Name="grdPWLGrid" Visibility="Visible" Height="440" Margin="0, 0, 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Name="dgPWLCGrid" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#FFE8F9FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="255" Margin="10,62,0,0" Width="693" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CanUserResizeRows="False" >
            </DataGrid>

            <Button x:Name="btnPWLPrint" Content="Print" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="307,388,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Background="#FFEEFFFF" Click="btnPWLPrint_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I am calling a stored procedure in my database to get the data. I use the Report Wizard to create my report rdlc. I called it `PrintWeeklyList.rdlc`.  For Choose a DataSource Type I selected Database. For Choose a Database Model I select DataSet. For Database Object I choose a stored procedure called `GetPrintWeeklyListData`. I gave the Data Source the name `PrintWeeklyListDataSet`. I gave the DataSet the name `PrintWeeklyListDS`.

Here is my C# code to load the the ReportViewer:

```
private void RVWeeklyList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!isReportViewerLoaded)
        {
            ReportViewer rvWeeklyList = new ReportViewer();

            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 =
                new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();

            PrintWeeklyListDataSet dataset = new PrintWeeklyListDataSet();

            dataset.BeginInit();

            reportDataSource1.Name = "PrintWeeklyListDS"; //Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
            reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.GetPrintWeeklyListData;
            rvWeeklyList.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);

            //rvWeeklyList.ServerReport.GetDataSources();
            rvWeeklyList.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
            rvWeeklyList.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "PrintWeeklyList.rdlc";

            dataset.EndInit();
            PrintWeeklyListDataSetTableAdapters.GetPrintWeeklyListDataTableAdapter pwlTableAdapter =
                new PrintWeeklyListDataSetTableAdapters.GetPrintWeeklyListDataTableAdapter();
            pwlTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
            pwlTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.GetPrintWeeklyListData);


            rvWeeklyList.LocalReport.Refresh();
            rvWeeklyList.RefreshReport();


            isReportViewerLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

When I step through the code I see that both dataset and rvWeeklyList have the data from the stored procedure in them. I have been searching Google and I can't figure out what I am missing to get the data to show. Any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `WindowsFormsHost` to `Visibility="Visible"`

Second, ensure that the `PrintWeeklyList.rdlc` file's `Build Action` is set to `Embedded Resource`

Now use the revised code below and be sure to replace the substring`<VisualStudioProjectName>` with the name of your Visual Studio project for the `ReportEmbeddedResource`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rvWeeklyList.Load += RVWeeklyList_Load;
}

private void RVWeeklyList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isReportViewerLoaded)
    {
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 =
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();

        PrintWeeklyListDataSet dataset = new PrintWeeklyListDataSet();

        dataset.BeginInit();

        reportDataSource1.Name = "PrintWeeklyListDS";
        reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.GetPrintWeeklyListData;
        rvWeeklyList.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);

        rvWeeklyList.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
           @"<VisualStudioProjectName>.PrintWeeklyList.rdlc";

        dataset.EndInit();

        PrintWeeklyListDataSetTableAdapters.GetPrintWeeklyListDataTableAdapter pwlTableAdapter =
            new PrintWeeklyListDataSetTableAdapters.GetPrintWeeklyListDataTableAdapter();
        pwlTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        pwlTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.GetPrintWeeklyListData);

        rvWeeklyList.RefreshReport();

        isReportViewerLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

MSDN article reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx

Comment: #sly -- I made the changes you suggested.  I now get this error, "An error occurred during local report processing. The report definition for report 'PrintWeeklyList' has not been specified. Object's reference not set to an instanceof an object."

Comment: @Cass Can you tell me what the name of the Visual Studio project is? I think that the ReportEmbeddedResource string is still incorrect. If possible let me know what it is being set to.

Comment: #sly -- I apologize.  I forgot to replace the <VisualStudioProjectName> with my project name.  Once I fixed it the report displays.  Thank you!